# How can I toggle a drop down menu by using an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code that attempts to create a dropdown menu using AngularJS, but it doesn't work:

CSS:

```
.display_none {
  display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div dropdown>
    <div class="drop_down display_none">
      <div id="elementWrap">
        // stuff
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module("app")
  .directive("dropdown",function(){
    return function(scope,element){
      element.bind("click",function(){
        if(element.find('.drop_down').hasClass('display_none'))
        {
          element.find('.drop_down').removeClass('display_none');
          element.find("#elementWrap").stop(true,true).delay(100).slideDown(350);
        }
        else
        {
          element.find("#elementWrap").stop(true,true).delay(100).slideUp(350,function(){
            element.find('.drop_down').addClass('display_none');
          });
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I click and nothing happens.

Comment: Are any errors throwed? Also, see my answer below.

Comment: Bonus points for trying to use a directive.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should read through this:

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Then, you should have a look at this:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

angular-ui provides ui.bootstrap.dropdownToggle. You could either use that or inspect [that code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js) and rebuild it's functionality.

Since you are already using a directive, you could use `element` in a linking function, rather than search-and-modify it the jQuery (lite) way.

Comment: The thinking an Angular post is a great place to start

Answer (score 0):

find() - Limited to lookups by tag name using angular jqLite, so you have to use jquery plugin.